What's that little animation between Avatar: The Last Airbender Book 2 and Book 3?
I remember there was a short animation that was mostly just still images that was canonically set between Book 2 and Book 3 of Avatar: The Last Airbender, centered around Aang having an out-of-body experience or something, and meeting various old Avatar spirits, after what happened at the end of Book 2.
I don't remember much more about it, but I know I've seen it referenced at least once on this site, but I can't seem to find it despite searching for ages. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGw2_Namw1M&ab_channel=Avatar%3ATheLastAirbender this thing?

No, the thing I remember was more like still images, or at least a very low frame rate, and possibly no spoken dialogue, just subtitles. I think it was supposed to bridge the gap between the end of Book 2 and the start of Book 3. Thanks for the suggestion though...

Sounds like a DVD extra. I could check my DVD backups, but it takes a while to download (and the originals are currently 60km away).

I could actually not find any extras on the last season 2 DVD or the first season 3 DVD. Also, this made me notice that my backup is faulty, most episodes are laggy in a weird way. I guess I need to redo those backups one day! Your description sounds like a deleted scene, maybe you can search on YouTube for it. If you find it, please write an answer below.

There was a bonus disk in one of the Avatar Book 2 DVD collections, "The Complete Book 2 Collection", that includes a feature that's described as an animated graphic novel / online game titled "Escape from the Spirit World."  In it, Aang encounters the spirits of several previous Avatars and faces a number of challenges in order to progress in his quest to restore his injured spirit:



